# UnsatisfiedLinkError when switch from Java 1.6.31 to Java 1.6.32+

Tags: java, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Trying to use such tools as *SVNKit* and *Cobertura* i seem to have come across an error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

Does anyone know of a workaround or do i now have to make a choice, Java 1.6.32 upwards or keep functionality required.

Answer (score 0):

Googling around, there is clear evidence that there are two different signatures for the `createFileExclusively` method in different versions of Java.  In some cases it is:

```
java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
```

in others

```
java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z
```

In other words there is a second `boolean` argument in some versions.

My theory is that somehow you are launching a JVM using an rt.jar file that doesn't match the native methods in the `java` executable or in one if its DLLs.  This could be due to an incorrect -Xbootclasspath, or something like that.  Or maybe you've got a messed up JDK or JRE installation.

Comment: i will check, as i think the underlying thing with cobertura is that it calls java, and may call a different version then the once i am running it with. just weird everything works fine on the older version

Answer (score -1):

That method is in the [Java 7](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/io/Win32FileSystem.java#Win32FileSystem.createFileExclusively%28java.lang.String%29) and beta release of Java 8. If your copy of Java can't find it I would check it has been installed correctly.

Comment: works correctly in java 1.6.31, does't work in 1.6.32 upwards

Comment: Hmmm, This change is in Java 6 update 37, but not in Java 7 update 9. Or Java 8 ea.